# Rest mass of electron-positron would be the same as their energy in annihilation?

Tags: special-relativity

If the combined mass of an electron and a positron was approximately $1$ MeV/$c^2$, then would the total energy of their annihilation be equal to $9 \times 10^{16}$ MeV? Why do we not multiply the rest mass by $c^2$ to get the energy that would be produced?

Please explain in layman terms.

Answer (score 3):

We do multiply the mass by $c^2$ to get the energy. The mass is roughly $1$ MeV/$c^2$ and when we multiply this by $c^2$ we get $1~c^2$ MeV/$c^2$ = $1$ MeV.

Comment: Obviously this discussion refers to particle/antiparticle at rest. Right?

Comment: @Alchimista Yes, $E=mc^2$ only applies to objects at rest. For the general case the formula is $E=\sqrt{(mc^2)^2+(pc)^2}$, where $p$ is the momentum.